# Analyse wave stream

Tags: audio, implementation, analysis, fft, wav

I've been looking to into audio analysis. I have a WAV stream read into memory and I neeed to perform various functions on the data, such as an  FFT. I've been reading the theory for this but I'm not sure I'm reading it correctly. When reading the stream, I get a bunch of numbers outputted, which I guess is the sampled data (at 44100 hz). Do I perform all the functions on this very stream? So, for a window of 1024 samples, do I simply get the first 1024 numbers from my stream? Then do I perform an FFT and all the other functions on this 1024 set and repeat for the rest of the stream?

I'm beginning to understand the theory of it, and the idea of summing the samples etc... but I'm not sure what this means in implementation terms.

Edit - To clarify the stream values I get, the numbers are along the lines of `-0.432,-0.065...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an brief overview of what you can do. For details I would suggest you look into some literature.

Before applying FFT the audio signal needs to be pre processed or windowed.
Let's say you are taking a window(hanning etc.),
the window function will be applied on the raw-audio with some 'overlap' to take care of edge effects. you can take a convenient window size of 1024 for example. After windowing you can take FFT per 1024 (pre-processed) samples.

I suggest you use MATLAB. That will make your task simple.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So do I apply the window function to the `-0.432,-0.065...` values mentioned in my post? i.e. the values I get from reading the stream from memory? So something like this: `var arr = StreamArray.Take(1024).ToArray(); FFT(arr);`, then the next 1024 etc..

Comment: yes the window function should be applied to the raw audio that you are receiving from the audio input and then you can do FFT. Also there has to be some overlap for e.g. take first n = 1 to n = 1024 samples then take the samples from n = 1024-128 to n = 1024-128+1024... like this